# Trying to fix this INSERT UPDATE on DUPLICATE query

Tags: php, mysql

New to PHP and SQL trying to get the syntax correct

```html
<?php
include("php/functions.php");
$userId = $_SESSION['userID'];
include("connections/conn.php");
?>
```

UserID brought from session

This is the query i'm looking to correct

```html
$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO 
selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selfesteemscore SET selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' , UserID = '$userID' ";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

On duplicate key update query [has slightly different syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO  selfesteemscore (
      selestscore
    , UserID
) VALUES(
      'NEW VALUE'
    , 'NEW USER ID VALUE'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      selestscore = 'NEW VALUE'
    , UserID = 'NEW USER ID VALUE'
;
```

Or better, to not to repeat new values twice:

```
INSERT INTO  selfesteemscore (
      selestscore
    , UserID
) VALUES(
      'NEW VALUE'
    , 'NEW USER ID VALUE'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      selestscore = VALUES(selestscore)
    , UserID = VALUES(UserID)
;
```

WARNING: read about SQL injections and escape values or use prapered statements.

P.S. you initializing variable $userId, but later on using variable $userID

Comment: Adding `{$...}` does nothing for SQL injections. Not sure why you adjusted that.

Comment: Sure, this is not about protecting from injections.I did not know that php will substitute value without brackers in double quoted strings. I removed them completely as I'm added SQL queries only without all these php related stuff.

Comment: PHP can interpolate which is where a lot of SQL injection bugs come about. The convention with placeholders is to put `?`

Comment: @fifonik I'm getting the User ID from the Session variable then updating the score based on that Session ID, the User ID in the first snippet has a smaller u due to it being that in the user's account table to reduce redundancy. the UserID in the scores table has a capital U. Is there a way of replicating your query to incorporate the Session ID ?